# Weird Footer Behaviour in IE & Webkit

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, safari, footer

i've got the following weird problem: if you go to XX you'll see a black footer at the bottom. well... at least in Firefox and Chrome.

In Safari the Footer isn't even showing, and i don't know why. If i give a little `margin-top:200px;` to the footer it will be visible in safari but way to much down in all other browsers, so it seems that in safari the footer is behind the content.

in IE 10 i got the problem that below the black footer is around 300-400px white space and i've got no idea why ?!

Maybe some of you could help me with that and spot the error i'm having... thank you!

Comment: here is good link that can help you http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Answer (score 1):

That's because of your `.wrapper`'s `margin: -190px auto;`. Find a way to fix it as you want. You can for example just remove the bottom one like this:

```
#wrapper{
   margin: -190px auto 0
}
```

Comment: thanks for your fast answer ! unfortunately it didn't work. i even set the wrapper to 0 auto just for test and the same error remains :(

any other ideas ? :)